# ought not to do or ought not do

Tags: modal-verbs, semi-modals

There are two sources, which contradict each other.

[The first one](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/oughtto.html):

> Notice "Ought not" Remember that "ought to" loses the "to" in the
>   negative. Instead of "ought not to," we say "ought not."

[The second one](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ought-to):

> You say that someone ought not to do something: She ought not to go.
>
> You can also use oughtn’t: She oughtn’t to go.

So, what is correct: *ought not to do* or *ought not do*?

Comment: I trust the Longman source, and [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/ought-to)

Comment: Yes, it seems that there are a lot of sources insisting on "_ought not to do_" variant...

Comment: No no, my mistake. American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style says, the *to* is sometimes omitted, but it's not commom in writing. So, I think it's fine :)

Comment: So, do you mean that it is just an British vs American difference in usage of _ought_?

Comment: According to NGram, the former isn't widely used in both [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+not+do%2Cought+not+to+do&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cought%20not%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cought%20not%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0) and [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+not+do%2Cought+not+to+do&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cought%20not%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cought%20not%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What I meant was, the *ought not do* is acceptable, but it's uncommon.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. The former isn't widely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"to"* in *ought not to* is optional in *informal non-assertive context*, which is particularly associated with negation.

But it's more natural to say *She oughtn't to go* or just use *should*, *she shouldn't go*.

---

*New Fowlers Modern English Usage*