# Oughtn't have or Oughtn't to have

Tags: grammar

Once, I had read a piece of information about the phrase "ought to" which implied that I can leave out "to" when it comes in the negative & interrogative form. For example:

> She oughtn't (to) have bought bread for lunch. We already had some.

Is that piece of information correct or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware that "oughtn't" is extremely unusual in the US. Many people will not even recognize it as a word until you explain it to them.

Comment: "Oughtn't to have brought bread" sounds insanely wrong to me, whereas "out not to have bought bread" sounds ok. Maybe I'm fried. In any case, I agree with @JeffreyCarney that "oughtn't" is weird in the US - basically, avoid.

Comment: Google ngram viewer says "oughtn't to have" is much more common, but there are also examples of "oughtn't have". Both seem to be in current use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ought not to do or ought not do](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122170/ought-not-to-do-or-ought-not-do)

Comment: 'Oughtn't have' without 'to' seems a fairly common casual Midwest/Southern US English usage going back to at least 1919 - two examples at random: _I thought I oughtn't have taken a berth In the sleeper, but your mother insisted_ (1919) _One thing to argue it oughtn't have been up since he declared candidacy_ (2020)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, no, you need the 'to' infinitive, just as you would in a normal infinitive construction.

> She ought to have brought bread.

> She ought not to have brought bread.

(It may help you not to use the contracted form.)

However I can think of contexts in which omitting the 'to' is acceptable, and probably preferable.

> She ought to run to catch the bus.

> She oughtn't run to catch the bus.

I presume (and I don't know for sure), that this practice has arisen due to how the synonymous 'should' is used in English.

> She should run to catch the bus.

> She shouldn't run to catch the bus.

However, using 'ought' in the second example, would be considered quite unusual and probably archaic. In both cases 'should/shouldn't' is probably easier to use, and 'ought' would not be expected in general conversation.

#### Edit

Looking at the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ought-to), I believe the 'to' *should* always be present in the negative form, however it is sometimes omitted in ways that sounds natural to an English speaker. In other words, you are probably safer always including the 'to', than guessing when you can omit the 'to' and possibly getting it wrong.

Better still, just say 'should/shouldn't'.